# InnoDB's data file(ibdata1, *.ibd) HEXA edit

Tags: mysql, hex, innodb

I have a question about InnoDB's data file. `(ibdata1, *.ibd)`
How can I read it?! And how can I edit it?!

There is a tb1 table: `(i int, c char(10))`.

I inserted 3 records: `(123, 'abc'), (456, 'def'), (789, 'ghi')`.

When I opened the data files `(ibdata1, *.ibd)`
I can't find and read that table and records.

How can I read it and edit it?
I want to know about that algorithm.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for comment, If record is deleted from client, then I want to restore that record.(not using dump or another solution.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an excellent series articles from Jeremy Cole on InnoDB internals, files format. http://blog.jcole.us/innodb/

He also wrote a [tool](http://blog.jcole.us/2013/01/03/a-quick-introduction-to-innodb-ruby/) that works with InnoDB tablespaces and shows different kind of information.

Format of an InnoDB page and a record I presented on one of Percona conferences http://www.slideshare.net/akuzminsky/recovery-of-lost-or-corrupted-inno-db-tablesmysql-uc-2010

Comment: Thank you, akuzminsky.
Your advice is so Helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Without understanding Innodb Internals you cannot read or edit ibd file. Please read [Innodb Internals](http://www.slideshare.net/mysqlops/innodb-internal-9032556) so that you can learn about idb a little.

Comment: Thank you for PPT. and If you known more depth information??

Comment: @SeonghwanKim I don't know further materials. But [MySQL Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/innodb-more-page-information.html) says that *"The most relevant InnoDB source-code files are `page0page.c`, `page0page.ic`, and `page0page.h` in the page directory"*. Note that it will be very difficult and sophisticated job. Good luck to you.

Comment: Thank you, InoS Heo. I'll looking at it.